# Calling a private function from within a public function in the same class

Tags: function, syntax, vb6

I have the following functions:

```
Public Function SaveExample() As Boolean
```

&

```
Private Function ValidateExample (ByVal vlngvariable As Long) As Boolean
```

I want to be able to call the second function from within the first.  But I get:

"Compile error: Argument not optional"

Is what I'm trying to do possible, and if so, what is the correct syntax?  I've simply tried adding the line:

```
ValidateExample
```

Within some of the logic of the first function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you should specify a value for parameter `vlngvariable`.

For example, within the function `SaveExample()` call `ValidateExample(x)` where `x` is the value that `ValidateExample` is expecting.

Answer (score 5):

Its not related to its access modifier, it expects an argument that you do not supply, so you would need to call it with one;

```
ValidateExample 1234
```

Or make it accept an optional argument

```
Private Function ValidateExample (Optional ByVal vlngvariable As Long = -1) As Boolean
```

Which would make `vlngvariable` within `ValidateExample` equal `-1` if called with no argument;

```
ValidateExample
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message you got contains the solution: The argument is not optional. So you need to pass a value to the function (7 in my example):

```
ValidateExample(7)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not even 100% which Language this is... but would the call not be something like

```
long vlngvariable  = 1000
Boolean result = ValidateExample(vlngvariable)
```

The function requires an argument passed by value.